# Converting Logical sector to CHS tuple on an SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, sectors

I'm getting myself used to x86 assembly, so I figured I'd start with some 16-bit programs. To test myself, I'm creating a program that will load data off a disk, copy it to memory, and then use it for the next bit. It's going to replace the MBR, so I can only use basic interrupts (the full thing is going to be a sort of "joke virus" for my use only).

The interrupt to read data off a disk and place it in memory requires arguments in CHS format, however my main drive is an SSD. I can't find anything online that will help me in this situation, because SSDs obviously do not work on cylinders.

My question is, is there any way to "convert" a logical sector number on my SSD to a CHS tuple to trick the program, or is that impossible?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be possible to look up the number of logical cylinders, heads and sectors for a drive in the BIOS (as a user - it's also possible to do this programatically, since the Linux fdisk utility used to do that, but no longer does). You can then solve for c, h and s using the formula

A = (c ⋅ Nheads + h) ⋅ Nsectors + (s − 1)

where A is the LBA address, Nheads is the number of heads on the disk, Nsectors is the maximum number of sectors per track, and (c, h, s) is the CHS address (from [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder-head-sector#CHS_to_LBA_mapping)).

It's also possible to *change* the CHS geometry values in the BIOS - but don't do this, as it will render any operating systems that rely on it, like Windows, unbootable.